# Can't Upgrade Ionic Version on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I'm trying to update my Ionic Cli from 6.12.2 to the latest version (6.19.0). I'm using Ubuntu. I was able to update node.js to the latest version, but when I run the commands:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
```

with or without sudo command, when I run `ionic -v` again, it still say that I have the version 6.12.2 of ionic. and when I run `npm install -g @ionic/cli` and then run `ionic -v` it still say the same. Those commands are not being able to remove ionic from my Ubuntu.

That is something like a cache folder on ubunt that I should delete from system, related with the ionic cli, or something like that? Because I was not able to do this following the documentation on website.

Comment: Are you able to see the latest version when using `npm view @ionic/cli versions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around the problem, you can install the latest version from tarball:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic/cli/-/cli-6.19.0.tgz
sudo npm -g install cli-6.19.0.tgz
```